# Azure vnet outbound block internet access except some domain

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, vnet

currenty I have a vnet with NAT gateway attached. Multiple VM's are connected to the vnet. How can I allows only certain domains (e.g. Domain A, Domain B) and restrict all other internet access to the VM's.

NSG doesn't let to use domain names. I am left with Azure Firewall but it is expensive. Any other recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: Deploy a proxy server within your VNet and configure it to allow access only to the desired domains (Domain A, Domain B). Route all internet-bound traffic from your VMs through the proxy server, **Microsoft Forefront TMG** can act as a router, an Internet gateway, a virtual private network (VPN) server, a network address translation (NAT) server and a proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure vnet outbound block internet access except some domain.

To restrict internet access to only specific domains within an `Virtual Network` you can install a `proxy server` and route all internet traffic through it.

**Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway** acts as a **router, Internet gateway, VPN server, NAT server, and proxy server**. making it a versatile solution for network security and `access control`.

**Install Microsoft Forefront TMG**

Deploy `TMG` within `Virtual Network`. You can install a`TMG` as a `virtual machine` within `Azure VNet`.

**Configure TMG as a Proxy Server**

Once **TMG** is configured, it will act as a `proxy server`. This involves setting up `TMG` to receive and process internet traffic from the `VMs` within your `VNet`

**Route Traffic through TMG**

Configure the `network settings` of your VM within the VNet to route all internet traffic through the **TMG** proxy server. You can do this by updating the network interface settings `or` configuring routing tables to direct traffic to the `TMG` instance.

**Reference**: [Install and Configure Forefront Threat Management Gateway (TMG) in Microsoft Azure](https://techgenix.com/install-and-configure-forefront-threat-management-gateway-tmg-2010-microsoft-azure/)